# Sqlalchemy : make join between 2 columns containing the same data but in different form and different type

Tags: python, join, types, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, one (table1) contains a column (columnA) which contains Ids of type int, for instance 12302394.

The other table (table2) contains a column (columnB) which contains the same data but in type string and in a different form, for instance 'Agent:12302394'.

I am used to do this :

```
select(...).select_from(table1.join(table2, table1.c.column == table2.c.column)
```

but it only works when the columns have the same type and contains the same data.

How can I make a join between these two tables on these two columns ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to [cast](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) one of the id columns to the type of the other in the join.

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
q = sa.select(t1.c.id, t2.c.id).select_from(
    t1.join(
        t2,
        t1.c.id
        == sa.cast(
            sa.func.substring(
                t2.c.id,
                sa.func.length(sa.literal('Agent:')) + sa.literal(1),
                sa.func.length(t2.c.id),
            ),
            sa.Integer,
        ),
    )
)
```

This is the generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t2.id AS id_1 
FROM t1 
  JOIN t2 ON t1.id = CAST(
    substring(
      t2.id, 
      length('Agent:') + 1, 
      length(t2.id)
    ) 
    AS INTEGER
  )
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I got this error : 
`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Agent:16609580' to data type int`. I had in mind to remove non-numerical values from the column that I want to convert, but I have difficulties doing it.

Comment: Ah, my bad I didn't notice that your key was alphanumeric. Do all the ids start with `Agent:`?  Which database are you using?

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately the data comes from an external database, so I do not have my hands on it. And yes, all the ids start with "Agent:".

Comment: I've revised it to handle the prefix. `substring` ought to work on most databases.

Comment: I got an issue with the substring function, I've been testing stuff since you responded but unfortunately I didn't get why it does not work.

`Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Agent:16606514' to data type int. (245) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: `func.substring(t2.c.id, 6, 9)` returns `:16609589`,
but `func.substring(t2.c.id, 7, 8` returns the whole thing `Agent:16609589`

Comment: Check the docs for the substring function in your database (I think you're using MS-SQL server, right?). Perhaps it uses  0-based indexing (I was testing on SQLite, which uses 1-based indexing, but checking on PostgreSQL, it uses 0-based, so `substring` is less portable than I thought).